# How do I tar multiple files (which are listed in another file) to their own separate tar in a different directory?

Tags: linux, bash, archive

I have the following folder structure:

```
parent/subdir/dir1
parent/subdir/dir2
parent/subdir/dir3
parent/subdir/dir4
```

I want to create the following:

```
parent/archive/dir1.tgz
parent/archive/dir2.tgz
parent/archive/dir3.tgz
parent/archive/dir4.tgz
```

The files `<dir#>` are listed in a file called `foo.txt` which resides in `parent/`

I want to create a shell script that will read in each dir from `foo.txt`, tarball them to their new location, and remove the original dir. I *do not* want all the dirs in `foo.txt` to be made into one large .tgz file. Any help?

Comment: Sorry, but it is unclear what you actually ask... Certainly you should read the file line by line and feed the line content into a `tar` command. That is obvious, so what _exactly_ is it you cannot find out yourself after reading the manual pages?

Answer (score 1):

Please see if this script is what you need. This script takes two arguments. The first argument is the file containing location of directories(**foo.txt**) and the second argument is the location where to save tgz files(**parent/archive**).

```
#!/bin/bash
while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
    cd "$2";
    echo -e "Archiving $line";
    tarName="$(basename "$line").tgz";
    tar -zcvf "$tarName" "$line";
    rm -Rf "$line";
    echo -e "Archived $line to $2/$tarName and removed $line";
done < "$1"
```

Comment: `tarName="$(basename "$line").tgz"` would be better

Comment: @m13r - Thanks for your inputs. I've updated the script.

Comment: This works beautifully! Thank you! I'm pretty sure I can mod as necessary, but is there a way to output the success of all the commands into a new file? It has been suggested to me that only those archives that run to completion should be removed.

Comment: @jprx - If I understand your question correctly, do you want to check if archive process is complete and then remove?

Comment: Yeah. I want to see if the archive process is complete and then if the process is successful, remove.

Comment: @jprx - The above script removes the directories only after tar command is complete. If you are using some external tape drive for archival, you might have to introduce additional lines with commands to wait until completion.

Comment: @jprx You could check the return status code of the tar call with the `$?` variable. A value of `0` would mean that everything was done without errors.

Answer (score 0):

Use the tar -T flag to specify a file which has a list of files to create a tar archive with.

Comment: That is exactly what the OP specifically says he does _not_ want to do...